# How to group by max date with un-unique field

Tags: sql, sql-server, maxdate

What would be the best SELECT statement to get max Event date to achieve the below mentioned Desired Table?

Scenario : An Order Can have multiple events in its lifecycle.. like Order Cancelled Event, order placed on hold event.. etc.. and each event records a note in the notes table.

Below are the Event & Notes Table.. and I only want the last recorded event and it's note.

**Table 1 : EVENT Table**

[image]

**Table 2 : NOTES Table**

[image]

**Desired Table**

[image]

**UPDATE :** In the desire table I only want to get the max event date, and the note for that max event for each order ID where Event Reason is 'On Hold'. So the OrderID will be unique identifier in the desired table

Comment: It is not clear how you arrived at your desired output.

Comment: I want to see all the orderID where Event reason is on hold and the latest event only.

Comment: This information should be a part of your question, not a side note.

Comment: based on your comment and your updated comment, the desired table has wrong data, either in the date values or in the note values, how come the note _Order Cancelled due to no payment_ should appears and you only take the Event Reason = 'OnHold' while it belongs to 'Cancelled' event reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte As (
Select Notes.OrderId, Tmp.MaxDate, Notes.Note, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Notes.OrderId Order By Notes.Note ) As rowNum
From
(Select EventId ,MAX(EventDate) As MaxDate 
From EventTable
Where EventReason = 'OnHold' 
Group By EventId ) Tmp
Inner Join Notes On Tmp.EventId = Notes.EventId 
)

Select OrderId, MaxDate, Note
From cte
Where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks mhasan, but still getting repating orderID.

Comment: Check now .. i have used cte to generate rownumbers for each order id and select one row

Answer (score 0):

Use **Partition By**:

```
SELECT
    X.OrderId,
    X.EventDate,
    X.Note,
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        N.OrderId,
        E.EventDate,
        N.Note,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By N.OrderId Order By N.OrderId,N.NoteDate DESC) AS PartNo
    FROM NOTES N
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[EVENT] E ON E.EventId=N.EventId
    WHERE N.EventId IS NOT NULL 
    AND N.Note like '%on hold%'
)X
WHERE X.PartNo=1
```

Comment: Thanks Sandip, I forgot to mentioned I only want those orders where Event reason is On Hold

Comment: I tried your query but it still the orderID is repeating.

Comment: it should not repeat as i have partition on it, you can write any where condition as per your requirement but you have to use partition to resolve your query

Comment: Check now and try, actually you have wrong info in requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT NT.ODER_ID, MAX(EV.EVENT_DATE), NT.NOTE
      FROM EVENT EV, NOTES NT WHERE
      EV.EVENT_ID = NT.EVENT_ID
 GROUP BY NT.ODER_ID, NT.NOTE 
 ORDER BY NT.ODER_ID;
```